# how work with contact ,camera, gps in flutter without using plugins

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to do CRUD on contacts and SMS using flutter, but after so much searching I feel flutter does not have any core options about contacts or SMS. there is nothing in the official documentation. 
how work with contacts, camera, GPS in flutter without using plugins?

Answer (score 0):

because the contact has a different implementation in android and IOS you need to have a code for each platform. in flutter its called Plugin or platform-specific code. and as I said there is no way to work with a contact without plugins cause its platform-specific code. if you don't want to use plugin You should write your own plugins for contact. and I think this is the hard way.

if you want to have your own plugin check [Writing custom platform-specific code](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels) link